# Spring Batch RepositoryItemReader HEAP SIZE issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are using Spring Boot 3.0.4 with Spring Batch 5.0.0 & Java 1.19.

We have created a Job with a RepositoryItemReader, processor & ItemWriter using chunks.
Basically we are reading chunks of records from one table (MySQL DB), then we convert the data into new objects in our item processor and then we write the entities back into a new table in the DB (MySQL DB).

We are testing with 1M records and chunks of 10K each.

We are seeing the heap size memory growing all the time during this step, and memory is not getting released.

We configured the step as below:

```
@Bean
public Step createTransactionsStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                   PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                   ItemReader itemReaderBillingTransaction,
                                   BillingTransactionWriter writer,
                                   RepositoryItemReader<BillingTransaction> myReader
                                 ) {

    return new StepBuilder(CREATE_TRANSACTIONS, jobRepository)
            .<BillingTransaction, Transaction>chunk(chunkSize,transactionManager)
            .reader(myReader)
            .processor(createTransactionsItemProcessor())
            .writer(writer)
            .listener(createTransactionListener)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemReader<BillingTransaction> myReader(BillingTransactionRepositoryCustom repository,
                                                         @Value("#{jobParameters[bsLogId]}") String bsLogId) {

    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortMap = new HashMap<>();
    sortMap.put("recordId", Sort.Direction.ASC);

    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<BillingTransaction>()
            .repository(repository)
            .methodName("findByBsLogIdAndBsStatus")
            .arguments(Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(bsLogId), VALIDATIONS_IN_PROCESS.code))
            .pageSize(chunkSize)
            .sorts(sortMap)
            .saveState(false)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<BillingTransaction, Transaction> createTransactionsItemProcessor() {
    return new CreateTransactionsItemProcessor();
}
```

Below is our implementation of CreateTransactionsItemProcessor

```
public class CreateTransactionsItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<BillingTransaction, Transaction> {


@Autowired
TransactionCreator transactionCreator;

@Autowired
AshraitCfgRepository ashraitCfgRepository;

@Autowired
CustomRoutingDS customRoutingDS;

private String merchantId;

@Autowired
protected LogWriter logWriter;

private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Autowired
BillingLogRepository billingLogRepository;

@BeforeStep
public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    String gatewayId = getStepJobParameterValue(stepExecution, JOB_PARAMETER_GATEWAY_ID);
    String pid = getStepJobParameterValue(stepExecution, JOB_PARAMETER_PID);
    String bsLogId = getStepJobParameterValue(stepExecution, JOB_PARAMETER_BS_LOG_ID);

    Optional.ofNullable(pid)
            .ifPresentOrElse(this::initBillingLog, () -> {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });

    // Saving in a step context some parameters that will be used in continue
    customRoutingDS.setCurrentGatewayId(gatewayId);
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("ashVersion", ashraitCfgRepository.getAshVersion());
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("manufUse", ashraitCfgRepository.getManufUse());
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("manufId", ashraitCfgRepository.getManufId());
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("merchantId", merchantId);
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("GATEWAY_LOG_NUMERATOR",0);
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("RQUEST_ID",String.format("%s-%s-%s", pid, bsLogId, 0));
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("date", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
 }


@Override
public Transaction process(BillingTransaction item) throws Exception {

    Transaction tr;
    try {
        tr = transactionCreator.createTransaction(item, stepExecution);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logWriter.info(stepExecution, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    setJobExecutionContext(stepExecution.getJobExecution());

    return tr;
}
```

Below is our implementation of the writer:

```
@Component
public class BillingTransactionWriter implements
    ItemWriter<Transaction>, StepExecutionListener {

private JobExecution jobExecution;

@Autowired
protected LogWriter logWriter;

@Autowired
private GatewayLogRepositoryCustom gatewayLogRepositoryCustom;

@Autowired
private ShovarNumeratorRepository shovarNumeratorRepository;

@Autowired
private CustomRoutingDS customRoutingDS;

@Autowired
private EntityManagerDynamicQueryService<String> entityManagerDynamicQueryService;

@Override
public void beforeStep(@NotNull StepExecution stepExecution) {
    logWriter.info(stepExecution, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "BillingTransaction writer initialized.");
    jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();

 //   jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("GATEWAY_LOG_NUMERATOR", 0);
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("INSERT_TOTAL_NUMERATOR", 0);

}

@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends Transaction> transactions) {

    int incr = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("GATEWAY_LOG_NUMERATOR")).toString());
    int total = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("INSERT_TOTAL_NUMERATOR")).toString());

    List<Transaction> bts = (List<Transaction>) transactions.getItems();

    System.out.printf("Received list of size: %d total insert : %d, GatewayLog Numerator is : %d%n", bts.size(), total, incr);
    total += bts.size();

    List<String> transactionIds = insertToGatewayLog(bts);
    insertToTransactions(bts, transactionIds);

    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("GATEWAY_LOG_NUMERATOR", ++incr);
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("INSERT_TOTAL_NUMERATOR", total);
    String pid = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString(JOB_PARAMETER_PID);
    String bsLogId = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString(JOB_PARAMETER_BS_LOG_ID);
    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("RQUEST_ID", String.format("%s-%s-%s", pid, bsLogId, incr));
}
```

From our tests on 1M records, we need to consume ~8GB of free RAM for HEAP SPACE, otherwise we get the below exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep][taskExecutor-1][ERROR] Encountered an error executing step createTransactions in job batchJob 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Also, this memory does NOT get released after the job is finished.

We expected that using Spring Batch with the built in reader/writters with chunks would use the heap memory efficiently and release memory once a specific chunk is finished.

Comment: That should not be the case. Is the processor `CreateTransactionsItemProcessor` stateful? What is the type of `BillingTransactionWriter`? If it is a custom writer, please share its code.

Comment: `CreateTransactionsItemProcessor` has a very small state `StepExecution` for holding some parameters in the context - please see the code I added above.
I also added some of the `writer` code above.

Comment: There are two common causes for such an OOM errors: either items are not released by an item processor/writer, or too much data is stored in the execution context. The code you shared does not seem to do any of those, but I can't see from what you shared what the root cause could be. Have you profiled the app and identified which part is consuming memory? This kind of issue is not easy to diagnose without a minimal example that reproduces them: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example